# Encoding utf-8 with TIdHTTP->Put()

Tags: c++builder, indy

I want to PUT json data to a REST service with TIdHTTP.

It works, as long as I don't have scandinavian letter in the json-data (ÅÄÖ). Then the server rejects the message. I can send the same data OK with Postman, so it is not a server issue.

My code:

```
String JsonData = "{...}";

TStringStream *JsonStream = new TStringStream(JsonData);

IdHTTP1->Request->CustomHeaders->AddValue("user", AUser);
IdHTTP1->Request->CustomHeaders->AddValue("password", APassword);
IdHTTP1->Request->ContentType = "application/json";
IdHTTP1->Request->CharSet = "utf-8";

IdHTTP1->Put("https://restserver", JsonStream);

delete JsonStream;
```

I've found examples in Delphi, where you create the TStringStream with an encoding flag:

```
AStream := TStringStream.Create(SomeData, TEncoding.UTF8);
```

But I can not see how an eqvuivalent works in c++.

This is an multi device application written with C++Builder v10.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`TEncoding`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.TEncoding) class is declared in the `<System.SysUtils.hpp>` header, and has a static [`UTF8`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.TEncoding.UTF8) property (an [example of its use](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/en/TStringsEncoding_(C++)) is in Embarcadero's DocWiki).  In your case, the construction of the `TStringStream` should look like this:

```cpp
TStringStream *JsonStream = new TStringStream(JsonData, TEncoding::UTF8, false);
```

Comment: Great, it finally works! That was acctullay one thing I tried, but got compilation error. Now I looked into the declaration (http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.Classes.TStringStream.Create), and noticed there should be one more argument, AOwnsEncoding. Don't understand hat it is for, but I set it to true, and now it works. I can see that in Delphi it has default value true, but not in C++.

Comment: @Tomas `AOwnsEncoding` sets whether the `TStringStream` destructor frees the `TEncoding` object or not. Yes, the parameter has a default value of `true` on the Delphi side. Old versions of the Delphi compiler had a bug in HPP generation where default parameters were not outputted correctly, but I thought that was fixed a long time ago. Maybe not.